# EmEditorのSendKeys メソッドの書き方について

Tags: emeditor

画像のアドレス
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B07KYFXCND/
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]お世話になっております。
http://www.emeditor.org/ja/macro_shell_send_keys.html
こちらのSendKeys メソッドで変換キーはどのように記載しますでしょうか？

たとえば、
shiftキー＋変換キーです。

こちらのSendKeys メソッドページでは書いてないキーが多いようです。Windowsキーの書き方もありませんでした。
使える全部のキーのマニュアル記載をお願いできますでしょうか？
それと3つくらいのキーの組み合わせの記載方法はどう書きますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMEで使う<kbd>変換</kbd>キー、<kbd>Windows</kbd>キーを使用するには、次のように記述します。

- <kbd>変換</kbd>

`shell.SendKeys( "{CONVERT}" );` (EmEditor v20.6.909 以上)

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>変換</kbd>

`shell.SendKeys( "+{CONVERT}" );` (EmEditor v20.6.909 以上)

- 左側の <kbd>Windows</kbd>

`shell.SendKeys( "{LWIN}" );`

- 右側の <kbd>Windows</kbd>

`shell.SendKeys( "{RWIN}" );`

複数キー組み合わせは、たとえば <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> なら次のように記述します。

```
shell.SendKeys( "{CTRL DOWN}" );
shell.SendKeys( "{SHIFT DOWN}" );
shell.SendKeys( "{F3}" );
shell.SendKeys( "{SHIFT UP}" );
shell.SendKeys( "{CTRL UP}" );
```

(以下のように記述しても同じ意味です。)

```
shell.SendKeys( "^+{F3}" );
```

使えるキーの一覧を追記しましたので、以下をご覧ください (EmEditor v20.6.909 以上)。

| キー | パラメータ |
| --- | --- |
| ALT | % |
| ALT 下 | {ALT DOWN} |
| ALT 上 | {ALT UP} |
| APPS | {APPS} |
| BACKSPACE | {BACKSPACE}, {BS}, または {BKSP} |
| BREAK | {BREAK} |
| CAPS LOCK | {CAPSLOCK} |
| CLEAR | {CLEAR} |
| CTRL | ^ |
| CTRL 下 | {CTRL DOWN} |
| CTRL 上 | {CTRL UP} |
| 変換 | {CONVERT} |
| DEL または DELETE | {DELETE} または {DEL} |
| 下矢印 | {DOWN} |
| END | {END} |
| ENTER | {ENTER} または ~ |
| ESC | {ESC} |
| F1 | {F1} |
| F2 | {F2} |
| F3 | {F3} |
| F4 | {F4} |
| F5 | {F5} |
| F6 | {F6} |
| F7 | {F7} |
| F8 | {F8} |
| F9 | {F9} |
| F10 | {F10} |
| F11 | {F11} |
| F12 | {F12} |
| F13 | {F13} |
| F14 | {F14} |
| F15 | {F15} |
| F16 | {F16} |
| HELP | {HELP} |
| HOME | {HOME} |
| INS または INSERT | {INSERT} または {INS} |
| 左矢印 | {LEFT} |
| 左 WINDOWS | {LWIN} |
| マウス下 | {BTNDOWN button, x, y} |
| マウス上 | {BTNUP button, x, y} |
| マウス クリック | {CLICK button, x, y} |
| マウス ダブルクリック | {DBLCLICK button, x, y} |
| マウス移動 | {MOVETO button, x, y} |
| 無変換 | {NONCONVERT} |
| NUM LOCK | {NUMLOCK} |
| NUMPAD * | {NUMPAD*} |
| NUMPAD + | {NUMPAD+} |
| NUMPAD - | {NUMPAD-} |
| NUMPAD . | {NUMPAD.} |
| NUMPAD / | {NUMPAD/} |
| NUMPAD 0 | {NUMPAD0} |
| NUMPAD 1 | {NUMPAD1} |
| NUMPAD 2 | {NUMPAD2} |
| NUMPAD 3 | {NUMPAD3} |
| NUMPAD 4 | {NUMPAD4} |
| NUMPAD 5 | {NUMPAD5} |
| NUMPAD 6 | {NUMPAD6} |
| NUMPAD 7 | {NUMPAD7} |
| NUMPAD 8 | {NUMPAD8} |
| NUMPAD 9 | {NUMPAD9} |
| PAGE DOWN | {PGDN} |
| PAGE UP | {PGUP} |
| PRINT SCREEN | {PRTSC} |
| 右矢印 | {RIGHT} |
| 右 WINDOWS | {RWIN} |
| SCROLL LOCK | {SCROLLLOCK} |
| SHIFT | + |
| SHIFT 下 | {SHIFT DOWN} |
| SHIFT 上 | {SHIFT UP} |
| TAB | {TAB} |
| 上矢印 | {UP} |
| [仮想キー コード](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) #nnn | {VKnnn} |

ヘルプは v20.7 公開時に更新します。

Comment: バージョンアップありがとうございます。普通の英文字のA～Zとかは、可能でしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Aなら、`shell.SendKeys( "A" )` となります。

Comment: お世話になっております。shell.SendKeys( "{CONVERT DOWN}" );
shell.SendKeys( "{CONVERT UP}" );こちらは設定されてますでしょうか？不明のエラーが出ました。shiftやCtrlキーと同様のためダウンとアップの両方が登録できる必要があるようです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: shell.SendKeys( "{CONVERT DOWN}" );
shell.SendKeys( "{CONVERT UP}" );

とは書くことができないです。`UP` と `DOWN` が追加できるのは、表に書かれているように Shift、Ctrl、Alt キーのみです。

shell.SendKeys( "{CONVERT}" );

と1行で書けば同じ意味です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。キーのアップとダウンはキーマクロにとっては極めて重要になります。たとえばこちらのKoolertronのキーボードは、upもDownも全部出来ます。その画面の画像を追加しました。単純にAというだけでは動作しないです。現在の状態では動作できないことが多数発生します。よろしくお願いいたします。
http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B07RM2GFTY/

Comment: `shell.SendKeys( "a" )` と書けば、`a DOWN`、`a UP` の2つの動作を続けて行うのと同じ意味になります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。私はKoolertronは使ってます。たとえば、Aというキーを押し込んだ状態で0.5秒Sleepしてからupするとかの記述は可能でしょうか？upとDownが同時になっては、動作が限られます。そのためKoolertronでは同じAというキーを押すマクロでも単一に書くのとupとDownの3パターンの記述が出来るようになっています。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: どうしてEmEditorでマクロを書いて、**A**というキーを押し込んだ状態で0.5秒Sleepしてからupするとかの記述が必要なのかがわからないのですが。**Ctrl**、**Shift**、**Alt**などのキーは、他のキーと一緒に押す必要があるため、それらのキーはできるようになっています。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。必要な理由ですが、これはかなりこのテーマで試行錯誤しないと気がつかないことかも知れません。複数のソフトを連携させる場合に、たとえばAというキーに対してshiftとかと同様な意味を持たせることがあります。これはshiftと何々のキーみたいなありふれた組み合わせには組み合わせの数に限定があったり、既にデフォルトで設定され尽くされているため、他のソフトウェアに割り当てられた動作と衝突、ダブった動作を防ぐためです。そのため通常キーにも兼用、Down、upの3つの動作を割り当てられないと、途端に狭い範囲の設定しか出来なくなります。その根拠としてKoolertronのレビュー画像を載せさせて頂きました。その画像にはSというキーにupとDownの両方が書かれています。この画像は2019年投稿で私のレビューではありませんし、このような画像が容易にネットで見つけられると言うことと、他の人がそのようにマクロを記述して投稿していると言うことはそうする必要がある需要がある社会的証明になります。ただ、これはそのような必要性のある状態にならないと「なんでこの人はこんな意味不明な仕様にこだわっているのか？なんの必要性があるのか？」と思われるのもしかたないと思います。この仕様は必要な状況に陥って困った経験の人間にしか気がつかない仕様のためです

Comment: 画像にはSというキーにupとDownの記述があって合間にもSleepの記述していることをご確認ください。このマクロの書き方ができないとこのレビューを書いている人のやりたいことが出来なかったことになります。

Comment: EmEditor のマクロはあくまで **EmEditor の操作に使うマクロ** であって、"複数のソフトを連携させたい" のであれば Windows のアプリを操作するマクロ、例えば AutoHotKey 等を検討すべきではないでしょうか？

Comment: 次に公開するバージョンでは、すべてのキーで `UP`、`DOWN` が使用できるようにしました。公開までしばらくお待ちください。

Comment: バージョンアップしていただきありがとうございます。御厚意､感謝しております。